# how to change application context path for ContextLoaderListener

Tags: xpath, applicationcontext

In my application by default org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener looks for Applicationcontext.xml in WEB-INF folder. Now i want to move Applicationcontext.xml file to src/main/resources folder. But if i do this i get error java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml].

How do i specify ContextLoaderListener  to look for file in resources folder? please help

Answer (score 0):

If you added it to Mavens resources folder simply add:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to your web.xml.